Fetching data from a page which i'm not the owner of
I find the Facebook developers API documentation a bit confusing.
I'm building a small app using PHP and I would like to fetch/scrape data from a page which isn't belong to me.
is it possible using the API or i will need to scrape the data manually?
If it's possible, is it possible if i'm not the owner of the page as well?

Are you scraping Facebook pages or using Facebook to scrape? The question would be better if that were clarified and with an example of what page to scrape or some simple code to scraping.

Accessing data from a Facebook page that you don't own can be done using Facebook's Graph API, but there are limitations and restrictions in place to protect user privacy and prevent unauthorized access to data. It is possible to access data from a Facebook page using the Graph API, it requires creating a Facebook app, obtaining permissions, and following Facebook's policies and guidelines. If you're not the owner of the page, you may have limitations on the data you can access.
